# How do I get tab-completion to work in emacs shell after using a symlink?

Tags: emacs, symlink, tab-completion

When I'm in Shell mode and cd to a directory through a symlink, tab-completion of the cd command stops working. Is there a fix? I'm on Fedora Core 18 and using Emacs 24.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of solutions to this problem.  I happen to prefer my implementation which changes the prompt to contain the current path, which Emacs recognizes and uses to get the behavior you want.  Additionally, my solution hides the portion of the prompt which contains the path because I find it ugly.

My solution can be found in the blog post: [Emacs Tip #25 Shell Dirtrack By Prompt](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/08/emacs-tip-25-shell-dirtrack-by-prompt.html).

However, there are a number of other solutions which can be found on the Emacs Wiki or other places:

- [Shell dirtracking again](http://atomized.org/2008/08/shell-dirtracking-again/)
- Emacs Wiki [Shell Dirtrack By Prompt](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/ShellDirtrackByPrompt)